# Why have a (univalent-foundations) tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management, retagging

I just saw [this meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6309/21820) concerning a tag for NFU or more generally New Foundations. There is good reason not to have a tag for too specific tags, but then I also noticed that there is a tag for [univalent-foundations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/univalent-foundations). At present it has only 7 questions asked by only 5 people, so I think there is no reason to keep it.

Isn't the [foundations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foundations) tag good enough? Should we just remove the [univalent-foundations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/univalent-foundations) tag from all these questions and add the [foundations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foundations) tag (if not already there)?

Answer (score 7):

I think the reasons given to potentially remove the [univalent-foundations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/univalent-foundations) tag are misguided.

- > There is good reason not to have a tag for too specific [concepts]

  I would argue that in some cases there are very good reasons to have tags for specific concepts. In fact, I believe that at times these are *better* tags than many of our broader ones. Certain specific mathematical constructs/objects/etc. come up again and again in questions on this site, and it is often useful to group these together under a tag. Sometimes they go by several different names and notations in the literature, and so relying on site-search to find relevant questions is not always optimal.

  A couple that I have been involved in the creation of are [the-baire-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-baire-space) and [sorgenfrey-line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorgenfrey-line). I argue that these are much better tags than the much larger [compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compactness) and [connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connectedness), which have great ambiguity to their usage. And our extremely broad tags ([calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus), [analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis), [topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topology), [number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory), etc.) only serve to delineate the various branches of mathematics, but often say very little about the content of a specific question.
- > At present it has only 7 questions asked by only 5 people, so I think there is no reason to keep it.

  The size of a tag really has no bearing on its usefulness. Tags "are for sorting your question into specific, well-defined categories" in order to "connect experts with questions they will be able to answer" (see [this Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32041)). That a tag is small only implies that (currently) few questions have been asked under that tag. It does not mean that categorising these questions together is without merit.

---

That said, I am personally uncertain about the usefulness of a [univalent-foundations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/univalent-foundations) tag. My concern is that it is not clear to me how this tag differs from the [homotopy-type-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homotopy-type-theory) tag. I am not an expert in these matters, but my understanding is that there is considerable — if not nearly complete — overlap between these topics. So from my standpoint the question is whether [univalent-foundations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/univalent-foundations) should stand alone, or be synonymized with [homotopy-type-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homotopy-type-theory) (with one or the other as master).

But since univalent foundations (HoTT) constitute a specific, and perhaps currently non-standard, approach to mathematical foundations, using a separate tag to separate these questions from those about the currently-more-standard set-theoretic/ZFC foundations seems appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question, and for your answer, but then by your reasoning we ought to have a "new foundations" tag too, because indeed I've been having difficulty finding posts on it...

Comment: @user21820 I agree, as [I did](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6311) in the meta-post you linked to in the question. That was actually my first post on meta.math, and my persuasiveness left much to be desired.

Comment: Oh oops by the time I saw your answer here I had forgotten it was you who also gave an answer there. I guess we'll see what other people think!